# Obfuscating AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Hey guys, I'm doing an AJAX `POST` call - but with FireBug you can see all the details (allowing people to bypass the form).

Any tips on Obfuscating this `POST` (or something along those lines)?

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/query.php",
        cache: false,
        data: "action=getWordsByLetter&l="+letter,
        success: function(data){
            dataArray = data.split('|');
            $('#words').html('');
            for(var i = 0; i < (dataArray.length - 1); i++) {
                $('#words').append('<li class="w">'+dataArray[i]+'</li>');
            }
        }
    });
```

*I would prefer to write the code myself as opposed to depending on a plugin :)*

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I hope you realize that absolutely any solution you have on the client side can be bypassed by a determined person. Since any encryption routine you implement would be javascript, it would be available to the client and thus crackable.

Comment: Of course, but the generic people on the streets are less likely : ) +1 for you

Comment: Obfuscation doesn't add much security.

Comment: I'm confused, why can't you just validate the request with PHP on query.php?  You have a set of conditions that allow them to make that request, so just recheck those conditions on the php page before you process the request.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about what kind of manual requests you'd like to block? Bots? Fiddler?

Comment: @ryeguy What about a public-private key scheme? I know you could duplicate any one request by capturing it and resending but would it not possibly prevent future or differing requests sent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### First: reCaptcha

If bypassing the form is a major problem you can always include reCaptcha which should be included with each post of that particular form.

I don't know about the scenario you're solving, but this will make it more or less impossible to make programmatic POSTs.

### Second: Client side library

The other way is as suggested a client side library. You can either use a client library and make it easy on yourself or write your own code that will do something similar.

### Third: Dynamic field naming

As I understand your form has at least one field on it. And you should only process this form when it's been requested for firstly. What you could do is make this field's name completely dynamic:

1. Server side creates the form and sets some dynamic name to your field
2. Stores the name for later use or encrypt it on the server and store the crypt in a hidden field in the form
3. Server gets back data
4. If the field's name matches previously created name (either stored server side or provided in the hidden name) you should process it otherwise just ignore the request.

### Fourth: Change DOM structure

If there's a risk that results will be consumed by bots you can always change the structure of your document in various ways (change container elements, change their CSS class names, IDs etc). Make a list of changes (several of them) and user permutations with that. You can more or less always achieve the result seems visually the same to a human, but a machine will have hard times reading it.

### Standard stuff

1. Make the process slow for bots but it would work just fine for humans (a 5s delay should not be noticable by humans)
2. IP restriction - you can allow only one request per x minutes from the same location - this greatly depends on the nature of your form
3. [Honeypot pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29) that usually filters out bots from humans.

Comment: Craigslist does steps 1 and 3 for its postings.

Comment: @David Murdoch: Does it? Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yup, or they did about a year ago. They don't (or didn't used to) do Step 4 though...so a bot can muscle through the forms up to the point where it needs to fill out the captcha.

Comment: Thank you @Robert Koritnik - Very helpful!

Comment: +1! If you just want to block mass automated requests without even accessing the form, you can just give the form an ID/hash field that gets set by the server when rendering the form. Subsequent requests are only accepted with the correct hash(es) and only once. Captchas would be much safer though. The values in the form with associated fields are always visible to the user. The Names of the fields can be obfuscated though, by generating them  as hashes dynamically, sending them out of order (with css placement). It would be hell to script-control something like that.

Answer (score 2):

As obfuscation is client side, anyone can just look at your obfuscation code and tamper with the post - you don't gain much.

Secure the server side: Have a minimum word length and a flood protection (only accept X requests from a client in Y seconds), and make sure that people cannot get access to any data they should have not access to by simply asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you should make your server application so that it doesn't really matter if people bypass the actual form.

- Input is wrong or malicious? Deny the request.
- Form is submitted many times by bots? Add bot protection in the form of captcha or other human verification techniques, flood limits, etc.
- Form is part of a security thing? Add signing of the requests, just like you would with a (public) webservice API (OAuth comes to mind)

Always - ''always'' assume your client is corrupted, could be a bot, a hacker, etc. The service this POST is submitted to should simply not allow abuse.

Obfuscation is security through obscurity, and not a guarantee that nothing will be abused. In fact, in this case it might even make your application an order of magnitude more complex. In order to be effective, it'd have to 'randomize' the keys and values sent to your server, in which case the server itself should know which obfuscated key matches what value. In fact, I think you're not looking for obfuscations, but for encryption.